# When checking for a substring is the "in" operator or the "find()" method more pythonic?

Tags: python, string

I was wondering, if there are any benefits to checking for existence of a substring like this `my_path.find("Photos") != -1` over using the `in` operator like `"Photos" in my_path`?

Comment: The `in` operator makes your meaning clear and is far easier to read. I'd only use `find` if I actually needed the index.

Comment: @tzaman sounds like a valid answer to me...

Answer (score 3):

As the [official docu](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.find) says you should use `in` in your case. Only if you need to know the position of the substring you can use `find()`.